# -Yii- Update listView by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, listview, drop-down-menu, yii

I'm very new at Yii and PHP, and I have a question.

I need a listView to be updated by ajax filtering from a dropdown selection, and it is working fine but the problem is the pagination.
I filter the results in the controller and pass the dataProvider to the view to change the listView, but when y change the page from paginator it shows again all results instead of the filtered results.

Here is the code I have:

**The view (prueba.php):**

```
<?php
echo CHtml::beginForm();

echo CHtml::dropdownList('comunidades',$comunidad,$comunidades,
            array('empty'=>'- -')
    );
echo CHtml::submitButton("Enviar");
echo CHtml::endForm();

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
    array(
        'itemView'=>'lista',
        'dataProvider'=>$provider_ciudades,
        'id'=>'id_lista_ciudades',
    )
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('items_update', "$('#category_id').change(function(){
    $.fn.yiiListView.update('id_lista_ciudades', {
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        }
    );
});
return false;",
CClientScript::POS_READY);?>
```

**The controller(the action that renders the view):**

```
public function actionprueba(){
    if($_POST['comunidades'] != null)
        $comunidad = $_POST['comunidades'];
    else
        $comunidad = '';

    $criteria_comunidades = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria_comunidades->select="comunidad";
    $res_comunidades = Ciudad::model()->findAll($criteria_comunidades);
    if($res_comunidades != null)
        $comunidades = CHtml::listData($res_comunidades,'comunidad','comunidad');
    else
        $comunidades = null;

    $criteria_ciudades = new CDbCriteria();//Creiteria para la busqueda de las ciudades.

    if(strlen($comunidad) > 0)
        $criteria_ciudades->addCondition("comunidad='$comunidad'");//Condicion de comunidad.

    $provider_ciudades = new CActiveDataProvider('Ciudad',
        array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>3,
            ),
            'criteria'=>$criteria_ciudades 
        )
    );

    $this->render('prueba',
        array(
            'comunidades' => $comunidades,
            'provider_ciudades' => $provider_ciudades,
            'comunidad' => $_POST['comunidades'],
        )
    );
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it, I needed new action to POST the data from **prueba.php** and changed the submitButton by ajaxSubmitButton and replaced the listView by ajax.